# Can't fetch addons in GRASS GIS 7.0.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu, ubuntugis, add-ons

I'm setting up a new install of GRASS 7.0.4 (from Ubuntugis) on Ubuntu 14.04 and having trouble installing addons. Specifically, when I try to "fetch and install extensions from GRASS Addons," I receive the following error:

> Exception in thread Thread-3:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in
>   __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "/usr/lib/grass70/gui/wxpython/core/gthread.py", line
>   94, in run
>       ret = vars()['callable'](*args, **kwds)
>     File
>   "/usr/lib/grass70/gui/wxpython/modules/extensions.py", line
>   332, in Load
>       mainNode = self.mainNodes[self._expandPrefix(prefix)]
>   KeyError: u't'

Reinstalling GRASS has not helped.

Answer (score 1):

Due to adding new group of temporal addons, this was broken, fix is available in the upcoming GRASS version 7.0.5. In the meantime, you can still install extensions using g.extension module, either from command line, or through g.extension dialog.